# How to implement autocomplete while using locator in arcgis

Tags: autocomplete, dojo, arcgis

The below code is to find a location on map, once the location is entered in a textbox.Please note in the below code that I am using 'locator' instead of 'geocoder' as i would like to have custom textbox instead of the textbox provided by the 'esri/dijit/geocoder' and also i would like to get the geocoordinates values using locator.

In the below code, i would like to add 'autocomplete' feature in textbox that has the same functionality as of 'autocomplete' feature in 'geocoder'.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <!--The viewport meta tag is used to improve the presentation and behavior of the samples 
      on iOS devices-->
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no">
    <title>Find Address</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://js.arcgis.com/3.12/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://js.arcgis.com/3.12/esri/css/esri.css">
    <style>
      html, body { 
        height: 100%; width: 100%;
        margin: 0; padding: 0;
      } 
      #map{ 
        padding:0;
        border:solid 1px #343642;
        margin:5px 5px 5px 0px;
      }
      #leftPane{
        width:20%;
        border-top: solid 1px #343642;
        border-left: solid 1px #343642;
        border-bottom: solid 1px #343642;
        margin:5px 0px 5px 5px;
        color: #343642;
        font:100% Georgia,"Times New Roman",Times,serif;
        /*letter-spacing: 0.05em;*/
      }
     </style>

    <script src="http://js.arcgis.com/3.12/"></script>
    <script>
      var map, locator;

      require([
        "esri/map", "esri/tasks/locator", "esri/graphic",
        "esri/InfoTemplate", "esri/symbols/SimpleMarkerSymbol",
        "esri/symbols/Font", "esri/symbols/TextSymbol",
        "dojo/_base/array", "esri/Color",
        "dojo/number", "dojo/parser", "dojo/dom", "dijit/registry",

        "dijit/form/Button", "dijit/form/Textarea",
        "dijit/layout/BorderContainer", "dijit/layout/ContentPane", "dojo/domReady!"
      ], function(
        Map, Locator, Graphic,
        InfoTemplate, SimpleMarkerSymbol, 
        Font, TextSymbol,
        arrayUtils, Color,
        number, parser, dom, registry
      ) {
        parser.parse();

        map = new Map("map", { 
          basemap: "streets",
          center: [-93.5, 41.431],
          zoom: 5
        });

        locator = new Locator("http://geocode.arcgis.com/arcgis/rest/services/World/GeocodeServer");
        locator.on("address-to-locations-complete", showResults);

        // listen for button click then geocode
        registry.byId("locate").on("click", locate);

        map.infoWindow.resize(200,125);

        function locate() {
          map.graphics.clear();
          var address = {
            "SingleLine": dom.byId("address").value
          };
          locator.outSpatialReference = map.spatialReference;
          var options = {
            address: address,
            outFields: ["Loc_name"]
          };
          locator.addressToLocations(options);
        }

        function showResults(evt) {
          var symbol = new SimpleMarkerSymbol();
          var infoTemplate = new InfoTemplate(
            "Location", 
            "Address: ${address}<br />Score: ${score}<br />Source locator: ${locatorName}"
          );
          symbol.setStyle(SimpleMarkerSymbol.STYLE_SQUARE);
          symbol.setColor(new Color([153,0,51,0.75]));

          var geom;
          arrayUtils.every(evt.addresses, function(candidate) {
            console.log(candidate.score);
            if (candidate.score > 80) {
              console.log(candidate.location);
              var attributes = { 
                address: candidate.address, 
                score: candidate.score, 
                locatorName: candidate.attributes.Loc_name 
              };   
              geom = candidate.location;
              var graphic = new Graphic(geom, symbol, attributes, infoTemplate);
              //add a graphic to the map at the geocoded location
              map.graphics.add(graphic);
              //add a text symbol to the map listing the location of the matched address.
              var displayText = candidate.address;
              var font = new Font(
                "16pt",
                Font.STYLE_NORMAL, 
                Font.VARIANT_NORMAL,
                Font.WEIGHT_BOLD,
                "Helvetica"
              );

              var textSymbol = new TextSymbol(
                displayText,
                font,
                new Color("#666633")
              );
              textSymbol.setOffset(0,8);
              map.graphics.add(new Graphic(geom, textSymbol));
              return false; //break out of loop after one candidate with score greater  than 80 is found.
            }
          });
          if ( geom !== undefined ) {
            map.centerAndZoom(geom, 12);
          }
        }
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body class="claro">
    <div id="mainWindow" data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/BorderContainer" 
         data-dojo-props="design:'sidebar', gutters:false" 
         style="width:100%; height:100%;">

      <div id="leftPane"
           data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" 
           data-dojo-props="region:'left'">
        Enter an address then click the locate button to use a sample address locator to return the location for 
        street addresses in the United States. 
        <br>

        <textarea id="address">380 New York St, Redlands</textArea>
        <br>

        <button id="locate" data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Button">Locate</button> 
      </div>

      <div id="map" 
           data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" 
           data-dojo-props="region:'center'">
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

How to add 'autocomplete' feature in this code?

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by using your own custom textbox provided by esri/dijit/geocoder? The Geocoder dijit comes with default ESRI css to style the dijit, but nothing prevents you from overriding this with your own styles.

For instance you could add a class in your body tag to override the claro styles:

```
<body class="claro custom">
```

This way esri dijits will use claro by default, but if you define the same css selectors as the esri dijit and append them with your custom class, the dijit will use that instead. Here's a short example where we override 2 properties of the results element in the Geocoder:

```
/* Custom styles for the Geocoder dijit */
    .custom #myGeocoder .esriGeocoderResults {
        overflow: visible;
        z-index: 1000 !important;
    }
```

Comment: could you please see if this is related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63518860/arcgis-custom-search-input-for-geocoding

Answer (score 1):

The geocode dijit supports autocomplete using either the default locator or custom ones. Since you are referencing the default locator service you can just use the dijit and pass autoComplete in the options

```
<script>
  var map, geocoder;

  require([
    "esri/map", "esri/dijit/Geocoder", "dojo/domReady!"
  ], function(Map, Geocoder) {
    map = new Map("map",{
      basemap: "gray",
      center: [-120.435, 46.159], // lon, lat
      zoom: 7 
    });

    geocoder = new Geocoder({ 
      map: map,
      autoComplete : true
    }, "search");
    geocoder.startup();
  });
</script>
```