# ArcGIS custom search input for Geocoding

Tags: javascript, angular, ng-bootstrap

In a (JHipster generated) Angular project I want to use the [ArcGIS geocode REST API](https://developers.arcgis.com/labs/rest/search-for-an-address/) to Geocode an address string with typeahead selection on the results.

ArcGIS have already implemented address [search](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-widgets-Search.html) with a Javascript/Angular library. It has a search widget that looks like this:

[image]

However my projects forms are using ng-bootstrap inputs. To have a consistent look and feel I want to use a [ng-bootstrap typeahead](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/typeahead/api) input with my own implementation of Geocoding with typeahead. (Unless there is a way to style the widget - per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28210995/how-to-implement-autocomplete-while-using-locator-in-arcgis) answer)

In stackblitz I achieved getting the typeahead input to work with a array of sample addresses, but can not understand how to connect it to the ArcGIS REST API results.

```
export class AppComponent {
  private static ROOT_URL = "https://geocode.arcgis.com/arcgis/rest/services/World/GeocodeServer/suggest";

  readonly name = "Angular";
  readonly locations$: Observable<ReadonlyArray<Location>>;

  constructor(private readonly httpClient: HttpClient) {
    this.locations$ = this.getLocations();
  }

  private getLocations(): Observable<ReadonlyArray<Location>> {
    const searchString = "23 Queen";
    const httpParams = new HttpParams()
      .set('countryCode', 'AUS')
      .set('f', 'pjson')
      .set('text', searchString);
    return this.httpClient
      .get<{ suggestions: ReadonlyArray<Location> }>(AppComponent.ROOT_URL, {params: httpParams})
      .pipe(
        pluck('suggestions')
      )
    ;
  }
}
```

My attempt at the stackblitz is [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular7-http-client-e1rntj?file=src/app/app.component.ts).

A sample response from the REST API is [here](http://geocode.arcgis.com/arcgis/rest/services/World/GeocodeServer/suggest?text=treas&f=pjson).

How do I get the string from the input to the REST API and the results back into the typeahead dropdown?

Comment: Why can't you just overwrite the css classes that the widget uses? https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/guide/styling
They recommend using sass, but the same thing can be accomplished with plain css.

Comment: it would be nice to provide a stackblitz with typeahead and you attempt to connect it with search API